# vue2, watch not trigger

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, watch

I work on Laravel project, and my front is Vue 2.

I try to render an input form that changes by user,
and to trigger after the user changes anything.

I try to copy my react app to Vue, and want to use `useEffect` hook for the trigger.

The data: *loanTypingDetails* change,
and the function in watch does not trigger (console.log ..)

template

```
<form className="details-loan-input">
    <h4>
        <input
            type="number"
            name="loanAmount"
            min="10000"
            :value="loanTypingDetails.loanAmount"
            max="10000000"
            step="10000"
            @change="handleInputChange"
            required="{true}"
        />
        <span>סכום</span>
    </h4>
    <h4>
        <input
            type="number"
            name="loanPeriodYears"
            min="1"
            :value="loanTypingDetails.loanPeriodYears"
            max="50"
            step="0.5"
            @change="handleInputChange"
            required="{true}"
        />
        <span>תקופת הלוואה בשנים</span>
    </h4>
    <h4>
        <input
            type="number"
            name="annualInterest"
            :value="loanTypingDetails.annualInterest"
            min="5"
            max="50"
            step="0.5"
            @change="handleInputChange"
        />
        <span>ריבית שנתית</span>
    </h4>
    <h4>
        <input
            type="date"
            name="loanStartDate"
            :value="loanTypingDetails.loanStartDate"
            @change="handleInputChange"
            required="{true}"
        />
        <span>תאריך תחילת הלוואה</span>
    </h4>
</form>
```

script

```
...

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            loanTypingDetails: initLoanTypingDetails,
            loanDetails: null,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        handleInputChange(e) {
            const {
                target: { name, value },
            } = e;
            if (name === "loanStartDate") {
                this.loanTypingDetails[name] = value;
            } else {
                this.loanTypingDetails[name] = Number(value);
            }
        },
    },
    watch: {
        // loanTypingDetails(newValue, oldValue) {
        //     console.log(newValue, oldValue);
        // },
        loanTypingDetails: (newValue, oldValue) => {
            console.log(newValue, oldValue);
        },
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch is shallow by default: the callback will only trigger when the watched property has been assigned a new value - **it won't trigger on nested property changes.** If you want the callback to fire on all nested mutations, you need to use a deep watcher.

So your might need to change your watch to this:

```
watch: {
    // loanTypingDetails(newValue, oldValue) {
    //     console.log(newValue, oldValue);
    // },
    loanTypingDetails: {
      handler(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log(newValue, oldValue);
      },
      deep: true
    }
}
```

Comment: I got you, thank you so much it really worked!

Comment: and if I want a function to trigger when the user changes any input, are these best practices? i don't care about ten old value

Comment: @yakov **Deep watch requires traversing all nested properties in the watched object, and can be expensive when used on large data structures. Use it only when necessary and beware of the performance implications.**

Comment: @yakov if my answer did help you, i would appreciate if you accpet my answer for this question.

Comment: Ok I understand it may cost me in performance, I have another way that will take me less performance? I just want a function to be executed as soon as a user changes one field

Comment: I still can not confirm the answer because of the reputation @akzhol kadybek